# How to simulate MAR missing data in R?

Tags: r

I would like to simulate some missing data in R but am having trouble. I have created two variables ('pre' and 'post') that represent a measurement for the same individual pre- and post-treatment (i.e. paired data). I have been able to do it for data that is Missing Completely at Random (MCAR) - see below, but am unable to figure out how to code it for Missing at Random (MAR). For the MAR missing data, I would like to create 3 categories based on the pre-treatment observations that will determine how many of the post-treatment observations are missing. i.e.

For pre > 25, 40% post missing
For pre > 21 and ≤ 25, 30% post missing
For pre ≤ 21, 20% post missing

Can anyone help out? (I'd be really grateful!)
Thanks

```
set.seed(80122)
n <- 1000

# Simulate 1000 people with high pre-treatment (mean 28, sd 3) and normal (mean 18, sd 3) post-treatment. Correlation between paired data = 0.7.
data <- rmvnorm(n,mean=c(28,18),sigma=matrix(c(9,0.7*sqrt(81),0.7*sqrt(81),9),2,2)) # Covariance matrix

# Split into pre and post treatment and check correlation is what was specified
pre <- data[, 1]
post <- data[, 2]
cor.test(pre,post)

# Simulate MCAR
mcar <- 1 - rbinom(n, 1, 0.2) # Will create ~ 20% zero's which we'll convert to NA's
post_mcar <- post
post_mcar[mcar == 0] <- mcar[mcar==0] # Replace post data with random zero's from mcar vector
post_mcar[mcar == 0] <- NA # Change zero's to NAs
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I thought I'd take a crack at it.

**Simulate fake data as in the OP:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mvtnorm)

# Number of data values
n <- 1000

# Simulate 1000 people with high pre-treatment (mean 28, sd 3) and normal (mean 18, sd 3) post-treatment. Correlation between paired data = 0.7.
set.seed(80122)
data <- rmvnorm(n, mean=c(28,18),
                sigma=matrix(c(9,0.7*sqrt(81),0.7*sqrt(81),9),2,2)) # Covariance matrix
```

**Convert to data frame:**

```
data = as.data.frame(data)
names(data) = c("pre", "post")
```

**Simulate missing completely at random (MCAR) data:**

```
data$post_mcar <- data$post

set.seed(2)
data$post_mcar[sample(1:nrow(data), 0.2*nrow(data))] = NA
```

**Simulate missing at random (MAR) data:** First, we'll create a grouping variable, `frac`, whose value is the fraction of the group that we want to set to missing. We'll use the `cut` function to create these groups and set the label values, then we'll convert the labels to numeric for later use:

```
data = data %>% 
  mutate(post_mar = post,
         frac = as.numeric(as.character(cut(pre, breaks=c(-Inf, 21, 25, Inf),
                                            labels=c(0.2,0.3,0.4)))))
```

Now, group by `frac` and set a randomly selected fraction of the values to `NA`, using `frac` to determine the fraction of values set to `NA`.

```
set.seed(3)
data = data %>% 
  group_by(frac) %>% 
  mutate(post_mar=replace(post_mar, row_number(post_mar) %in% sample(1:n(), round(unique(frac)*n())), NA)) %>% 
  ungroup
```

Here are the last 6 rows of the resulting data frame:

> ```
>           pre     post post_mcar post_mar frac
> 995  28.63476 19.35081  19.35081 19.35081  0.4
> 996  32.86278 24.16119        NA       NA  0.4
> 997  28.25965 16.64538  16.64538 16.64538  0.4
> 998  24.35255 17.80365  17.80365 17.80365  0.3
> 999  28.12426 18.25222  18.25222       NA  0.4
> 1000 27.55075 14.47757  14.47757 14.47757  0.4
> ```

Here's a check on the fraction of values missing in each group. Note that the actual percentage of values set to missing can differ from `frac` if the requested percentage doesn't result in an integer number of rows. Here, for example, there's no way to select 20% of 8 values. It can be 12.5% (1 value) or 25% (2 values).

```
data %>% group_by(frac) %>% 
  summarise(N=n(), 
            N_missing=sum(is.na(post_mar)), 
            Frac_missing=N_missing/N)
```

> ```
>   frac   N N_missing Frac_missing
> 1  0.2   8         2    0.2500000
> 2  0.3 138        41    0.2971014
> 3  0.4 854       342    0.4004684
> ```